# how to store the content of each text file into associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

i am making search engine using associated array now i want to make an associative array of a path in which i can get key as a document and value as a content.

below is my code

```
    $file= 'D:\\data\\awd_1990_00\\';
        $dictionary = array();
        $docCount = array();

        foreach($collection as $docID => $doc) {
                $terms = explode(' ', $doc);
                $docCount[$docID] = count($terms);

                foreach($terms as $term) {
                        if(!isset($dictionary[$term])) {
                                $dictionary[$term] = array('df' => 0, 'postings' => array());
                        }
                        if(!isset($dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID])) {
                                $dictionary[$term]['df']++;
                                $dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID] = array('tf' => 0);
                        }

                        $dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID]['tf']++;
                }
        }

        return array('docCount' => $docCount, 'dictionary' => $dictionary);
}
?>
```

As you seen `$collection` is a associative array which i want to make kindly help me

Comment: Help you in what way? What's the problem?

Comment: @MattHolbrook-Bull as i have a folder in which i have multple text files now  i want to make associative array of these files like
array(50){
[1]=> content of first text file
[2]=> content of 2nd text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this function:

```
<?php

    function extractDocuments($p_dir) {

       if(!is_dir($p_dir)) {  //Check if $p_dir is a valid directory

        //Throw exception or return FALSE  
       }

        $path=$p_dir;
        $dir=scandir($path); //Load directory contents
        $collection=array();

        foreach($dir as $file) { //Go through directory
          if($file==".." || $file==".") {continue;} //Exclude parent directory and self
          $collection[$file]=file_get_contents($path.$file); //Load file contents and save
        }

        return $collection;
    }

?>
```

Comment: thanks man! you are great i have been working on this for a day thank you soo much !!!